# Edit Excel VBA Module to only email the last row of the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to edit this already slightly edited code (source: Ron de Bruin). Right now it emails all individuals in the spreadsheet. I would like it to simply perform the function in the For loop once; on the last row. Being new to VBA, this has proven difficult.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With 

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("D1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                     If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

To give a little bit more context, I am trying to couple this module with a UserForm to have it so an individual puts in their information and which attachments they would like emailed to them, and when it submits, it adds their info to a spreadsheet while simultaneously sending them the attachments.

In the code's current config, it would do that, but it would also email everyone every time a new entry is submitted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the last name using the loop and put your If statement outside of the loop and use mailing code only for this.

```
If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then 
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by this. Instead of a loop, shouldn't there be a statement equating the `cells` variable to last cell in column C?